# Are there any expressions to say "We were informed that - "

Tags: phrase-requests

Are there any other expressions to say "We were informed that - " when you write a business email? I would like to know a expression more like native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the context. If you wanted to be very formal (perhaps even hostile), you could use:

> It has come to our attention that...

http://www.nvtc.ee/e-oppe/Varkki/layout/2_sample_business_letter.html

A more neutral alternative could be:

> We have recently learned that...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The context that i'm most likely to use in business scene is like "We were told that , "we were heard that ". I guess that "It has come to our attention that" will suit in the context.

Comment: By context, I meant the content of the letter - esp.the parts of **what** has come to your attention, and what do you want to do about it.